# Replace text with an image docx4j

Tags: java, image, text, replace, docx4j

I have an word template. There is an word photo that has to be replaced with an image. This has to be done with Docx4Java.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclosure: I manage the docx4j project**

The **VariableReplace** code doesn't handle images.

The best way to do this would be to use data bound content controls, specifically a picture content control pointing via XPath at a base-64 encoded image in an XML document (see Getting Started for details).

However, if you want to replace a word with an image, you can do so, but you'll have to write a bit of glue code.  It is pretty straightforward.

First, find the word. You can do this using XPath or TraversalUtil (again, see Getting Started for details).

Hopefully it is in a run (w:r/w:t) by itself. If not, you'll need to split the run up so you don't replace adjacent text.

Then, add the image.  See the sample **ImageAdd**.

I suggest you have a look at the XML created when you add an image in Word (ie save and unzip your docx, then look at document.xml). Take care that the XML representing the image is at the correct level (eg child of w:p).

Answer (score 2):

If specifically looking to replace a text with an image(which is not possible using docx4j as answered above), you can use replace bookmark with image as an alternative.

Just open your templated word file, position the cursor at desired location and insert->bookmark and name your bookmark.
I followed the instructions [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/6413972878/) to replace this bookmark with an image